# Set fixed size for Text block SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui, layout

I have cell model, and sometimes I have long text in title and cell's size changes. Do you know how to fix text position and align it by first line?[image]

Comment: You'll need a [mre]

Comment: Looks like you want to use an [alignment guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-create-a-custom-alignment-guide) though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are wrapping the cells with HStack. Use `HStack(alignmeht: .top)`